# What can I do with the "Socket Error number 10053"

Tags: python, networking, error-handling, compiler-errors

I started to learn networks and in one of the exercises I was asked
to write a server which response multiple time to the same client
and I got this error

```
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I wanted to ask whether the problem is with the software and not my program, or its with my program.
Here are my server and client (I'm warning that they're pretty long :D)

Server:

```
import socket
import time
import random


def message_init(client_socket):
    """
    this method gets the socket of the client
    and waiting for a command from the client
    if the command is one of the commands the
    server is familiar with, the method returns
    a proper message. if its not a known command
    to the server, the server sends to the client
    'null' in order that it'll enter a new valid
    command.
    """

# starting message with 'Garbage' in case when
# the client will insert unsupported commands
message = 'Garbage'

while message == 'Garbage':
    # waiting for a command from the client
    client_command = client_socket.recv(1024)
    length = client_command[0: 2:]
    request = client_command[2::]

    # message is the proper reply for the request from the client
    if request == 'TIME':
        # message is the local time
        message = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

    elif request == 'NAME':
        # message is the name of the server
        message = "Daniel's Server"

    elif request == 'RAND':
        # message is a random integer between 1 - 10
        message = str(random.randint(1, 10))

    elif request == 'EXIT':
        # message is exit and closing the connection with the client
        message = 'EXIT'
        client_socket.send(message)
        client_socket.close()

    if request == 'Garbage':
        # sending 'null' to the client
        # in order that he'll sent a valid command
        client_socket.send('null')

# returns a message in proper to the command
return message


def send_message(client_socket, message):
    """
    Gets a message and the socket of the client
    sending to the client the number of bytes
    in the message and afterwards sending the
    message itself
    """

    new_message = ''
    length = len(message)
    if length < 10:
        new_message += '0'

    new_message += str(length) + message

    # sending the message to the client
    client_socket.send(new_message)


def main():
    """
    binding with every client that tries to connect.
    getting a command from him, and if the command is
    valid, the server does what the command asks for.
    The proper Commands:
    TIME: returns a string of the local time.
    NAME: returns a string of the name of the server.
    RAND: returns a string of number between 1 - 10.
    EXIT: closing the connection with the client
    """

    # creates a new socket
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    try:
        # binding with every client who asks for
        server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1729))
        # waiting to get connection from a client
        server_socket.listen(1)
    except socket.error, e:
        print e

    connected = False
    # an infinite loop of connecting with a client
    # getting a command from a client and sending
    # him proper response
    while True:

        if not connected:

            # getting the client socket and his address
            # and accepting the new connection
            (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
            connected = True

        # message gets a valid message using message_init function
        message = message_init(client_socket)

        if message != 'EXIT':
            # if there's still connection:
            send_message(client_socket, message)

        else:
            connected = False

        client_socket.close()
    # closing the socket of the server
    # (although on the current server and client it won't happened)
    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Client:

```
import socket


def valid_cmd(command, commands):
    """
    getting a command and a list of
    approved commands. returning the
    command when its one of the commands
    """
    while command not in commands:

        # waiting until the client enters a valid command
        command = raw_input("Please enter one command of the following:"
                            " TIME, NAME, RAND or EXIT ")

    # returns the command if its in commands
    return command


def send_request_to_server(my_socket, request):
    """
    getting a request and the socket
    sending to the server the request
    when there is its length before him
    in two digits.
    for example: 04RAND
                 04EXIT
    """

    length = len(request)
    message = ''
    # putting a zero before so the length will
    # be in two digits form
    if length < 10:
        message += '0'

    message += str(length) + request

    # sending the message to the server
    my_socket.send(message)


def handle_server_response(my_socket, commands):
    """
    Receive the response from the server
    and handle it, according to the request
    """

    # data gets the response from the server
    data = my_socket.recv(1024)

    # if the server returned null there was
    # a problem with the message so we ask
    # from the client to give us other message
    while data == 'null':

        message = raw_input("Please enter one command of the following:"
                        "TIME, NAME, RAND or EXIT")

        # checks whether the message is valid
        message = valid_cmd(message, commands)

        # sending the message to the server
        send_request_to_server(my_socket, message)

        # waiting for the server's response
        data = my_socket.recv(1024)

    # returns the data when it has valid value
    return data


def main():
    """
    connecting to the home server
    sending it a command
    and printing the server's answer
    """
    # creating a new socket
    my_socket = socket.socket()
    try:
        # connecting the client to the home server
        my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1729))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        my_socket.close()

    # a list of the approved commands
    commands = ['TIME', 'NAME', 'RAND', 'EXIT']

    stopped = False
    while not stopped:
        # asking for an input of command
        message = raw_input()

        try:
            # making sure that message is one of the valid commands
            message = valid_cmd(message, commands)

            # sending the message to the server
            send_request_to_server(my_socket, message)

        except Exception, e:
            my_socket.close()
            print e

        # data gets a valid response from the server
        data = handle_server_response(my_socket, commands)

        # checking it the server disconnected from the client
        if data == 'EXIT':
            stopped = True

        # keeping the length of the upcoming data
        # although there is no use for that on that program
        length = data[0: 2]

        # printing the data from the server
        print data[2::]

    # disconnecting from the server
    my_socket.close()

    lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    assert valid_cmd('b', lst) == 'b', 'valid_cmd should return' \
                                       ' the given value if its ' \
                                       'already in the given list'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: TLDR; Error 10053 is a WSA Error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2). It likely means either you have a virus scanner or firewall that is refusing to allow your session.

Comment: So how can I check if my program is fine or not?